# SQL Where Clause with Cast or convert doesnt work

Tags: mysql, casting, where-clause, arcgis

I've a table on ArcGis which contains nummbers and dates. I need to filter these via a sql-query. I just have the possibility to change the where clause.

See here: https://services3.arcgis.com/rKOPqLnqVBkPP9th/arcgis/rest/services/Arbeitsmappe1/FeatureServer/0//query

Just type in the where clause 1=1 and outfield * then you will get all results.

I have to filter installierte_leistung which contains numbers in the following formats: 
1.050,20 ; 18; 0,1 ; 1.230

and dates of following format: 11.04.08

wished filters:
installierte_leistung: I want to execute a sql-statement like: where (installierte_leistung BETWEEN '1' AND '2'). In the result there is also the 18. Or if I ask for values greater 10 it shows me also the 1.050,20.

I tried to convert with cast and convert to decimal, signed, unsigned, integer and so on, but the query has been always invalid. I tried with 'number' and with number and with "number". lowercase and uppercase and almost all thinkable possibilities. I get no results with cast or convert.

Same issue with the Date. I want to filter monthly. so means between 01.2008 and 09.2009 for instance.

Could someone please help me? Thanks a lot!

Falk

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past with nested query. The more database specific queries (like cast and so) don't work because ArcGIS server is by default configured to work only with standardized queries. If you need to use more specific queries you have to change "standardizedQueries": "false" in server setting, check here how (bottom of the page): http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//015400000641000000. Should work for you. Good luck.

Comment: great advice. Unfortunately everything is set to true in these settings.